# Add and change attribute / feature cascaded (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, sql, expression

I have a polygon layer with hierarchical polygons. The main polygon has a capital letter like 'A' or 'B'. All polygons inside the main polygon got a number and all inside them get a second, third, fourth... number. You can see it in the graphic below.

I want to create new polygons inside a other, they should get the letter and numbers of there parent features. And also if I change a parent, the child's (an maybe the "older" parents) should automatically update.
For example: in the second graphic, I changed the letter A to B. All related polygons should now update.
[image]

I did use an aggregate function to get the attributes of the parent feature. This works for adding new polygons but won't help if I change a parent. I think aggregate is not the perfect function since I'm working in just one layer:

```
aggregate('layer','concatenate_unique',to_string("parent"),within(centroid(geometry(@parent)),$geometry))
```

At the moment I use only one Geopackage-Layer for the polygons and would like to keep it that simple. But If there is a nice solution by using more layers or a "real" database, I'm okay with it! I'm running QGIS 3.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding a *VirtualField* to your layer (which will be calculated upon feature update/creation), using the following expression:

```
aggregate(
  layer:= 'Polygons',
  aggregate:= 'concatenate',
  expression:= Id,
  concatenator:= '-',
  filter:= contains($geometry, geometry(@parent)),
  order_by:= -area($geometry) 
)
```

In this case *Polygons* is the layer of interest, and *Id* is the field containing the base attribute to be rolled up. The result is an aggregate of the Id values a given polygon is contained by.

[image: Initial]
**Initial**

[image: After Insert/Update]
**After Insert/Update**

*Tested on QGIS 3.8.3*

Comment: It is simple and it works! But the aggregate function is consuming too much resources for 300 polygons. I thought to go the same way with a SQL virtual Layer - but I don't know how - any idea?